# JsPDF-AutoTable: Imagen no coincide con la fila en páginas adicionales

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Saludos. 
Agradezco la ayuda para lo siguiente con jSPDF AutoTable v2.3.0.

Tengo una tabla con imágenes en la primera columna con el siguiente estilo:

```
styles: {overflow: 'linebreak', columnWidth: 'wrap'},
    columnStyles: {
        0: {columnWidth: 25},
        1: {columnWidth: 350}
},
```

Cuando la tabla ocupa dos páginas, las imágenes no encajan correctamente en la fila.

Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/shinseiki86/60qrh6e1/

Resultado: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PykQw.png

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corregido utilizando el problema reportado en el siguiente enlace:
https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/93

```
  drawCell: function(cell, opts) {
    if (opts.column.dataKey === 0 && opts.row.index < data.rows.length) {
      images.push({
        elem: imgElements[opts.row.index],
        x: cell.textPos.x,
        y: cell.textPos.y
      });
    }
  },
```

Solución: https://jsfiddle.net/shinseiki86/j5dz8dv8/